# Data type suitable for couple of List <string> objects, as one container to hold both

Tags: c#, types

learning c# on my own , in a new project i have started working on,

one of the methods, accepts a `List<string>` type data, passed in as a parameter 
. i would like to know , now ...that the need is for **two** of those lists, two types of data, or two groups,

and just for this example , say i have a *pros*  and *cons*, or.. *girls* and *boys*,

these are actually 2 separated lists of elements or objects, i need to pass in, as a parameter 
, and i want it to be passed as-one data-Type, and then,  inside the method i will take care of separation of data lists , so.. instead of a couple of `List` objects i, thought(for a second there ,  that a `Dictionary` will be suitable...)

though i will only have one element (one item... each is a `List`) ,in this data type that i need to pass

what can i do to get this result ?

i will try to illustrate it :

```C#
List<string> classGirls = new List<string>();
List<string> classBoys = new List<string>();
```

for eace item in source... load both from the source

done List girls + List Boys are populated how would you pass them as one as a Dictionary Could though knowing you will only have One Girls And One Boys ListObjects ?

```C#
public bool foundAMatch( string Lookup, List<string> G , List<string> B){
{
    var firstGirl = G.ElementAt(0);
    var firstBoy = B.ElementAt(0);

    return firstGirl == Lookup && firstBoy !=Lookup ;
}
```

instead i need it to be something Like

```C#
  public bool foundAmatch(string Lookup, someDataType.... Kids)
  {
    var firstGirl = kids-girls <-- first entity in kids;
    var firstBoy = kids-boys <-- first entity in Kids; 

    return firstGirl == Lookup && firstBoy !=Lookup ;
  }
```

few things in mind ...as to  properties of data , it should have good performance... naturally desired,  though most importantly, it should be appropriate /easy to arrange and suitable for iterations using loops for sorting and as subject to all kind of statistic operations  .

- question is,

how will you implement the logic , is it an existing data Type... that i am thinking of **?**

if it's not,  what approach will you implement in this scenario  choosing / crafting  a data Type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this easily by using inheritance:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }  // The setter is private because we only have to set this name when we create an instance

    protected Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Male : Person
{
    public Male(string name) : base(name)  // This constructor calls the constructor of the class it inherits and passes on the same argument
}

public class Female : Person
{
    public Female(string name) : base(name)
}

public bool IsMatch(string needle, IEnumerable<Person> haystack)
{
    var firstGirl = haystack.OfType<Female>().FirstOrDefault();
    var firstBuy = haystack.OfType<Male>().FirstOrDefault();
    return firstGirl != null &&
           firstGirl.Name == needle &&
           firstBoy != null &&
           firstBoy.Name != needle;
}
```

edit:

I quite like extension methods, so I'd write the method like this:

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static bool IsMatch(this IEnumerable<Person> haystack, string needle)
    {
        // same method logic in here
    }
}
```

which you can then use like:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Male { Name = "Bob" });
people.Add(new Female { Name = "Mary" });
var isMatch = people.IsMatch("Jane");
```

edit2:

It's probably even better to just have gender as a property of the `Person` class:

```
public enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Sex Gender { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, Sex gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
    }
}
```

and change the method to:

```
var firstGirl = haystack.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Gender == Gender.Female);
var firstBoy = haystack.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Gender == Gender.Male);
```

Comment: thanks . that sure looks promising, though i was looking for a broader info , so as it looks really professional approach, .. if you could please , as i am a fresh /beginner with O.O.P  could you please supply not just a fantastic code but some more info ? what's inside Male:person did you just like that on the fly have created a new class that is now declared within same line ? could you better explain your code please ? what are you declaring as properties with in the abstract class to implement within the derives

Comment: There's an argument to be held over whether to use an abstract class or an interface. The benefit of abstract class is that you don't have to implement common members in derived classes. I updated the derived classes with a constructor that calls their base constructor. I also added another example where I used a Sex property in a single class to distinguish between the two genders.

Comment: wondering how long it took you only from zero to know what exactly are you talking about in this simple (in relation to all .net complexibility ) classes , how +when to use `enum` (currently till now i've used them for passed parameters as "mod" to method then switch on it ) so you have made a property out of it , it's like knowing what to do with wood , i would think of a wooden wall and you will show me a double deck penthouse ...

Comment: That's exactly how I feel about most people on StackExchange. Sometimes I just can't fathom how they all know so much.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get one collection is to create a class representing a boy as well as a girl. Please find the example below:

```C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private class Kid
        {
            public bool Gender { get; set; }
            public String Name { get; set; }
        }

        private List<Kid> kids;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // === Load data =================================================
            kids = new List<Kid>();
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "John", Gender = true });
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "Paul", Gender = true });
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "Jack", Gender = true });
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "Brenda", Gender = false });
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "Judith", Gender = false });
            kids.Add(new Kid { Name = "Sofia", Gender = false });

            Kid foundKid = foundAMatch("sofIa");
        }

        private Kid foundAMatch(string name)
        {
            var result = (from K in kids
                          where K.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower() 
                          select K);

            if (result.Count() != 0)
                return result.First();
            else
                return null;
        }

        private Kid foundAMatch(string name, bool gender)
        {
            var result = (from K in kids
                          where K.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower() && K.Gender == gender
                          select K);

            if (result.Count() != 0)
                return result.First();
            else
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```